# What happens to the Zend Framework routing tables when you change the site to a subfolder?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does anyone know exactly what happens when you change your Zend site at, say, `foo.com/` to `foo.com/subfolder/` ? I notice that routing breaks and either I am not using `front_controller.setBaseUrl()` properly or it has no effect. I am unable to find any formal documentation at the Zend site about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you need to set the `RewriteBase` parameter in your `.htaccess` file.

Assuming your rewrite rules look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And assuming you are moving your site into the `subfolder` subfolder, add the following line to your re-write rules, just under `RewriteEngine on`.

```
RewriteBase /subfolder
```

Your complete rewrite rules should look like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

PS: The Front Controller/Request Object/Router will 99% of the time correctly determine the `baseUrl` automagically. Try *not* explicitly setting it. If the above changes to your rewrite rules do not work, only then attempt to override.

You can, at any time get the `baseUrl` that was determined be the request with the following:

```
var_dump(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl());
```

Comment: I was using the older Zend RewriteRule: RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php without even using Rewritebase I'm seeing improvement! Great work!

Answer (score 0):

[Configuring your URL Rewriter](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you prepend the /newfolder/ to all your set_include_path statements in the config. Then setBaseURl should work properly.